# At Acts 4:12, does Peter indicate that God has put Himself "on the hook" to save in Jesus'name?

Tags: acts, soteriology

> Neither is there salvation in any other: for there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby **we must** be saved. - Acts 4:12

There are some few translation that render this as "can be saved" or "may be saved" but the vast majority have "must".

This definition from Abarim publications seems to justify the "must":

> The curious verbal expression δει (dei) or δειν (dein), which is basically an impersonal 3rd person singular form of our parent verb, meaning: it is needed, required, necessary, fitting or even morally obligatory. The imperfect form points to something that's been long deemed necessary: it ought to be so ... according to long-standing conviction. **The present tense refers to necessity derived from an acute situation**. Our verb is used 104 times

My question is, to whom does the "must" apply?  Is it that: 1) having called upon the name of the Lord, God "must" save that one?, 2) Salvation "must" be sought in the name of the Lord? or, 3) Another option which eludes me?

Answer (score 2):

Acts 4:12
Berean Study Bible

> Salvation exists in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given to men by which we **must** be saved.

must
δεῖ (dei)
Verb - Present Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 1163: Third person singular active present of deo; also deon deh-on'; neuter active participle of the same; both used impersonally; it is **Necessary**.

This word appears 104 times.
NASB never translated it as "may":

> due (1), had (7), have (2), must (56), necessary (4), needed (1), ought (17), ought to (1), should (9).

Thayer's Greek Lexicon:

> a. it is **necessary**, there is need of, it behooves, is right and proper ...
> b. **necessity** brought on by circumstances or by the conduct of others toward us ...
> c. **necessity** in reference to what is required to attain some end ...
> d. a **necessity** of law and command, of duty, equity ...
> e. **necessity** established by the counsel and decree of God, especially by that purpose of his which relates to the salvation of men by the intervention of Christ and which is disclosed in the O. T. prophecies

The word carries a strong sense of necessity.

OP: There are some few translation that render this as "can be saved" or "may be saved" but the vast majority have "must".

At https://biblehub.com/parallel/acts/4-12.htm, 37 versions use "must be saved"; 3 uses "can be saved"; 0 uses "may".

OP: My question is, to whom does the "must" apply? Is it that: 1) having called upon the name of the Lord, God "must" save that one?

No. Nowhere in this chapter is there any mention of calling upon the name of the Lord. The context isn't there. Instead, the name of the Lord is a metaphor for the power of the Lord.

2. Salvation "must" be sought in the name of the Lord?

Well, not exactly. The verse says that Salvation exists only in the name of the Lord. It does not have the word "sought".

At Acts 4:12, does Peter indicate that God has put Himself "on the hook" to save in Jesus'name?

No, not if you interpret it as some kind of magical formula.

Yes, if you meant that salvation must exist only in the name of the Lord. It is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

Remembering that it was God that chose Abraham  when  he was worshiping the god of his fathers to bless him and make him a great nation.

God tells the end from the beginning.

> I declare the end from the beginning, and ancient times from what is still to come. I say, ‘My purpose will stand, and all My good pleasure I will accomplish. Isaiah 46:10

As the story unfolds through all the ups and downs of the nation of Israel one thing is certain.  God may temporary  leave then so to speak and let them have their own way, but He always comes back for them.

He has given them many promises and even though they are unfaithful He remains true to His word.

It was prophesied through an angel that Jesus would save his people from their sins.

> and she will bring forth a Son, and you will call His Name Jesus, for He will save His people from their sins.” Matthew 1:21

God is not a man that should lie and nothing will stand in His way to keep His word.

It is Him alone that will save His people Israel.

He must save them!
There is no one else that can.

It is foretold throughout the Scriptures how that will be accomplished.

Here again is your question.

"My question is, to whom does the "must" apply?"
It is to His people Israel.

Would venture to say that Peter was  prophesying about house of Israel when he says this.

It is confirmed again later on through the apostle Pauls writing
And so all Israel will be saved, as it has been written:

“The One Delivering will come out of Zion,
He will remove ungodliness from Jacob.
27And this is the covenant from Me to them,
when I shall take away their sins.”  Romans 12:26

Comment: Are you saying that Acts 4:12 does not incorporate the gentiles even though it is one name given "amongst men" and not "given unto Israel"?

Comment: Mike,  At the time the context of this particular passage that you were inquiring about is spoken mainly to the leaders, scribes, elders, the high priest and the people of Israel.  Acts 1-4 bears this out.  It is concerning the name of Jesus. 
"In what power or in what name have you done this?  
Let it be known to all of you, and to all the people of Israel, that in the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth—whom you crucified,   And there is salvation in no other, for there is not another name under heaven having been given among men, by which it behooves us to be saved.” They

Comment: They commanded them not to speak nor to teach at all in the name of Jesus.
Peter is speaking to Israel at this time saying Jesus Christ, is the one appointed for them is their Savior.  Don't look for anyone else.
God, having raised up His servant, sent Him first to you.
After the nation of  as a whole rejected Jesus their king salvation was sent to the Gentiles.  Through the apostle Paul,  Jesus and His salvation through His name alone is proclaimed to all others.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Greek usage of the verb is similar to the Romanian, given that both are intimately connected to Latin, the second option seems the most likely; i.e., just as a man can be with many women, but is bound by the vows of marriage to seek romantic comfort only in the arms of his lawfully wedded wife, so also Christians must seek such salvation exclusively from the **one** true God, through the grace of His **only** Son, as opposed to any other rival or alternate options available in the ancient world, be it Pharisaic legalism, or pagan polytheism; the context itself seems to reflect this:

> <sup>Acts 4:12</sup> Neither is there salvation in **any other**: for there is **none other** name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved.

i.e., one must, or has to, or is allowed to be saved, or seek salvation, only through these specific means, and not by any other; see also 2 Corinthians 11:14.

Comment: This seems to me to be the natural reading of the text.